# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key [Tableview error]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i am working on a application which has a `table view` inside a `UIView`.i have only one cell to display in the `tableView`. but it has to be a customised cell. i have added some lables and image into the cell. Before i added them as `IBOutlets` my app was running without an error. but immediately after i added `IBOutlet`, app crashes and showing me an error in error log as ,

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <myKey>
```

so far what i have done is , i added a `UItableViewCell` class to my customized cell. and also i added delegate and data source to my `UIViewController` class. and inside the `cellForRowatIndexPath` i tried this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"creditCardCell";

CreditCardCell *cell = [self.cardCell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CreditCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

if i remove the Outlet from my UITableViewCell class, then app is working without any error. please help me someone. tell me what should i do for this.

Comment: what is self.cardCell?

Comment: CreditCardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: yes agree with @rcat24

Comment: it is my outlet to the TableView inside the Uiview :(... my view controler is not a tableviewController class.

Comment: i got same error although i changed the code as you mentioned @rcat24  
error : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cardName.

cardName is my outlet in the tableViewCell

Comment: @DipenChudasama  i have edited the code as mentioned. but i am getting the same error.. and the key that the error is mentioning is my outlet which i have connected to the tableViewCell

Comment: You named your tableView outlet as cardCell? You need to make sure that in the interface builder you have the custom cell's outlets go to whoever owns the cell... for example - a UITableViewCell class called "cardCell"... and over there you do the login of the cell.

Comment: @rcat24 im using Storyboard. so my cell owned by a UITableviewCell class named CreditCardCell. i have added the outlets to that class and connected with the UI. what do you mean by login of the cell...?

Comment: if you use cell in IBoutlet then why you need to alloc cell again...? USE only outleted cell....no need to alloc it again...

Comment: guys... i could able to fix the issue.. i have used initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier in my cell Class.. so that helped me.. thank you very much for your cooperation :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IBOutlet for the cell. Make the prototype cell in tableView and

Add this in .h file and connect it with storyBoard/xib

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Do this in cellForRowAtIndexPath in .m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"creditCardCell";
CreditCardCell *cell = (CreditCardCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CreditCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: i didnt have to check this method. because  initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier helped me :) thank you very much for your time @nikola